# Optimisation in Python with time series parameters, Pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization

I am optimising an energy system that supplies energy from two sources of natural gas and hydrogen to end-users with varying demand in a week period (in hourly time steps).

I used Pyomo and the ipopt solver to model the system which is working properly. I have two lists of inlet parameters (demand and hydrogen) in my CSV file in two separate columns (and 700 rows as I said there is an hourly time step).

I want to optimise the system for each time step and generate the OF and calculate the variables per time step (per hour for all rows). The error is

> Index '(1, 'NG')' is not valid for indexed component 'X'

I was thinking to use the function for each variable and constraint "def" but I couldn't succeed to get the results.

I would appreciate it if you could take look at the code and let me know how can I repeat the optimisation for each time step.

```
    import pyomo.environ as pyo
    from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
    from pyomo.environ import *
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib as mp
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    from pyomo.dae import *
    import numpy as np
    
    data=pd.read_csv('H2_Demand_Week.csv')
    
     
    date_numbers = data['Time']
    
    y = data['Demand_MWh'] 
    y2 = data['H2_Curtailed_10MWh']
    
    m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
    Nd=len(data)
    
    
     
    cost_NG = 0.066 #the NG price is 0.066 €/kWh in Ireland in March 2022
    cost_CW = 25 #curtailed wind cost is 25 €/MWh
    cost_Storage = 470 #€/MWh
    cost_H2_out = 0.044 #€/nm3
    cost_H2_in = 0.5 #€/nm3
    WI_NG = 48  #the natural gas Wobbe Index MJ/m3
    WI_H2 = 41 #the hydrogen Wobbe Index MJ/m3
    
   
    
   
H2_perc=0.05

yd = data['Demand_MWh'] 
yh = data['H2_Curtailed_10MWh']


T = range(len(data))


data.replace([np.nan], 0, inplace=True)

#sets and paramenters
#m.setInv = pyo.Set(initialize=['NG','H','S'])

m.NG = pyo.Var(T, bounds=(0,None), initialize=1)

m.H = pyo.Var(T, bounds=(0,None), initialize=1)

m.S = pyo.Var(T, bounds=(0,None), initialize=1)

#constraints
#m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = pyo.summation(m.X) == Demand)
for i in range(1,Nd):
    m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = m.NG[i] + m.H[i] ==yd[i])
    

for i in range(1,Nd):    
    m.C2 = pyo.Constraint(expr = m.H[i] + m.S[i] == yh[i])
    

for i in range(1,Nd):    
    m.C3 = pyo.Constraint(expr = m.H[i]/(m.NG[i] + m.H[i])<= H2_perc) #hydrogen concentration


#objective function
#m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = m.X['NG']*0.066+m.X['H']*0.5+m.X['S']*cost_Storage, sense=pyo.minimize)
for i in range(1,Nd):
    m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = m.S[i]*cost_Storage, sense=pyo.minimize)


#begin = time.time()

#solve
opt = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='C:\\ipopt.exe')
#opt = SolverFactory('couenne', executable='C:\\My_Files\\_H2_HYDROGEN_THE_GREEN\\ThisPC_MODELLING\\PYTHON-MODEL\\ENERGY SYSTEM OPTIMISATION\RHODE\\Couenne-0.3.2-win32-msvc9\\Couenne-0.3.2-win32-msvc9\\bin\\couenne.exe')

#opt.options['tol']=1e-3
#opt.solve(m)
m.results = opt.solve(m)

#detalT = time.time() - begin

#print
m.pprint()

print('\n\nStorage:',pyo.value(m.S))


print('\n\nOF Storage cost €:',pyo.value(m.obj))
```

Comment: You're definint that the index for your `Var` X are `m.i` (i.e. a RangeSet {1,2,3...t}) but in almost all your constraint your trying to retrieve it with double index. `m.X[i,'NG']+m.X[i,'H'] == m.Demand[i]`. That's the problem

Comment: Thanks for your comments @pybegginer. PLease see the code now. I edited the code and have this error now "'IndexedVar' object is not callable". it is just calculate the last row and the value of the other time steps are shown zero.

Comment: Could you please paste the traceback error?. But I guess that's happening because you're trying to call `pyo.value(m.S)`. Since `m.S` is an `IndexedVar` (indexed by `m.T`) you need to call each value (`m.S[1]` for instance) you can use `m.S.display()` to see all values in each index. BTW I think your formulation have mistakes since you're replacing constraints and stuffs, I'll try to show you in some sparse time